# What is the difference between pessimistic and optimistic pruning of decision trees?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I am trying to understand decision tree pruning methods. I tried several sources but none of them clarified how pessimistic and optimistic pruning works. Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Pessimistic pruning builds a sequence of DC from the initial one and at each step, one rule is removed such that its removal brings the lowest error among all possible removals. This pruning returns the smallest tree with lowest error. Thus the name pessimist. the method tries to observe everything and checks whats the worst that could happen and avoid that.

In optimistic pruning, each internal node of the DT is tested only once in a bottom-up fashion and the local error is estimated over the examples reaching that node. If the local error after removal is not greater than the local error before, plus a penalty term, then the node and its subtree is removed. This results in over pruning and thus the approach becomes optimistic i.e. it will be all better kind of thinking.

There are papers on both the topics where they have mentioned the formula for both and the meaning of terms in those formulas.